# Is there a way to force operator overriding in subclasses?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to declare that an extending class must override a particular operator? For example, given class 'BaseClass' and A : BaseClass, B : BaseClass, is there a way to force both 'A' and 'B' to define an operator override for >= .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot force derived classes to define an override for an operator because operators are static.

You could do something like this:

```
using System;

abstract class BaseClass {

    public static bool operator >= (BaseClass x, BaseClass y) {
        if (x is null || y is null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot compare null values.");
        }
        return x.GreaterEqual(y);
    }

    // If you define an operator, you must define its matching operator as well.
    // Just throwing NotImplementedException for the example.
    public static bool operator <= (BaseClass x, BaseClass y) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public abstract bool GreaterEqual(BaseClass y);
}

class A : BaseClass {

    public int SomeValue;

    public override bool GreaterEqual(BaseClass y) {
        A other = y as A;
        if (other is null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot compare null or non-A values.");
        }
        return SomeValue >= other.SomeValue;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        A a1 = new A { SomeValue = 1 };
        A a2 = new A { SomeValue = 2 };
        bool test = a1 >= a2;
    }
}
```

This would force your derived classes to define the `GreaterEqual` method.

Comment: Obviously real code would check for null first before calling `x.GreaterEqual`, and maybe match the types but code shows the idea.

Comment: Yes, this was just to give the idea :)

Comment: Anyway, adding some checks and actually make it compile wasn't a big effort after all.